# update item property upon index to stored array in angular 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects that look like this

```
0:{price: 43, index: 103}
1:{price: 47, index: 103}
2:{price: 42, index: 103}
3:{price: 45, index: 102}
4:{price: 48, index: 102}
5:{price: 46, index: 102}
6:{price: 44, index: 102}
length:7
```

The value should not add in the array, instead, it should update the previous value if the index matches with the previous index of an array, else the value should add up in the JSON array.

```
0:{price: 42, index: 103}
1:{price: 44, index: 102}
length:2
```

The code I am running right now is given below :

```
updateValue(prices,indexes) {
    let v = {price: prices,index: indexes};
    this.newPriceList.push(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need first to check if there is an item with those index in the array. If yes - update price for that item, if no - just add it into the array.

```
updateValue(prices, indexes) {
   const found = this.newPriceList.find(item => item.index === indexes);

   if (found) {
      found.price = prices;
   } else {
      this.newPriceList.push({ price: prices, index: indexes });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do following

```
updateValue(prices,indexes)
{
    const oldItem = this.newPriceList.filter(item => item.index === indexes)[0];
    if (oldItem) {
        oldItem.price = prices
    } else {
        const v = {price: prices,index: indexes};
        this.newPriceList.push(v);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do it by using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```
arr = [{price: 43, index: 103},
{price: 47, index: 103},
{price: 42, index: 103},
{price: 45, index: 102},
{price: 48, index: 102},
{price: 46, index: 102},
{price: 43, index: 102}];

processed = arr.reduce((acc, v) => {
  acc[v.index] = v;
  return acc;
}, {});

result = Object.values(processed);

console.log(result );
//=> Array [Object { price: 43, index: 102 }, Object { price: 42, index: 103 }]
```